# Regular expression for a string containing at least one number

Tags: java, regex

Can someone please explain what the following regular expression means?

```
^(?=.*[\p{L}\p{M}0-9]).{6,50}$
```

It forces users to have at least one number in their username.

How should I modify it to remove this constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `0-9` constraint set in the look-ahead:

```
^(?=.*[\p{L}\p{M}]).{6,50}$
```

Now, it allows a string containing any symbols but a newline, from 6 to 50 occurrences, and at least one Unicode letter.

To use it in Java, you need to double-escape backslashes:

```
String pattern = "^(?=.*[\\p{L}\\p{M}]).{6,50}$";
```

Comment: This was exactly what I tried before posting this question. It does not work. I checked it both on my application and [here](https://regex101.com/#javascript). Am I missing something?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: This is a web application written in Java.

Comment: Java regex is better tested at [regexplanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRjBtpYRDA/index.html), or in the IDE. Here is a demo of what the regex validates in PCRE (it is similar to Java flavor): https://regex101.com/r/oW0iY2/1. As you see, there must be at least 6 and up to 50 characters and there must be at least 1 letter inside. Also, you must remember that in Java, you need to use double backslashes: `String pattern = "^(?=.*[\\p{L}\\p{M}]).{6,50}$";`